# Anchor Point Calibration (Cyclicality, Central Tendency) - Probability of Default (PD) Question about assessment - Credit Risk

Tags: credit-scoring

Let's assume we have a PD model that was calibrated with the following parameters:

```
Long Run Average (Central Tendency - CT): 5%
Cyclicality (ω): 50%
Default Rate (DR): 10%
Anchor Point: CT(1-ω)+ωDR = 5%*(1-50%)+50%*10%=7,5%
```

These were parameters calculated let's say 5 years ago.

I read that in order to assess the calibration, I need to test whether `0.7*PD > Anchor Point or Anchor Point > 1.3*PD.`

`PD` is the estimated probability of default for the portfolio.

Do I use the same values as the ones calibrated in the previous calibration (5 years ago)? Or do I need to update the ω,DR,CT values with most recent ones? Also, in the PD, do I put the most recent portfolio default rate or do I calculate PD differently?

Any references would also be nice, I tried searching online but there is not a lot of material available.

Comment: What is PD? Please explain (as an edit to the post.)

Comment: Do you expect that the same variables and the same variable values are just as good to predict current defaults as they were 5 years ago?

Comment: I edited my initial post. @Michelle I don't expect them to but what if this is how the Anchor Point Test works? It tests whether the calibration used is still valid or not.

Comment: This is well out of my area of expertise. I did a search for anchor point calibration, and all I found on methodology was: https://www.bis.org/ifc/events/ifc_8thconf/ifc_8thconf_4c4pap.pdf

Comment: Thank you Michelle but I don't see anything about anchor point in this PDF?